# Voltage drop with diodes

Tags: batteries, voltage

I have a battery case with a built-in led bar battery level indicator.  The case was made for a 36-volt battery, but I will be using it as a 48-volt pack.  I would like to drop the voltage to the battery indicator by 12-volts so it would be somewhat accurate.  Are diodes the best way to do this?  I do not feel like a regulator would be a good choice.   Thanks!

Comment: Yes a 12V regulator on the low side of the LED bar interface is the best way.  78L12

Comment: If you subtract 12 V your meter will become a 12 - 48 V indicator. Is this what you want or do you want to scale by 0.75 so it will be a 0 - 48 V indicator?

Comment: use a resistor-based voltage divider

Comment: I would simply use a 12 V **zener diode**. You can also do this with diodes but you will need a lot of them in series. "Somewhat accurate" does not mean much, if you want to be able to tweak the level, use a 11 V (or similar value) zener diode and add 2 diodes in series. If the reading needs to be lower or higher just add or remove diodes.

Comment: @Tony, can you inject current into 7812 output? If not, its output should be loaded with a resistor with low enough resistance...

Comment: @Transistor yes, I have a 48v battery and a 36v meter.  I want to use the meter to accurately(ish) reflect the voltage of the 48v battery

Comment: That information is already in your question. You didn't answer what I asked!

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTVTx2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 79L12 is a negative 12V precision regulator with a PNP output but a max Vio range that must be limited.